# How to use Apple Pkl for Spring Boot wit Maven?

Tags: spring-boot, pkl

I am following this instruction here https://pkl-lang.org/spring/current/usage.html to configure `pkl` for my spring boot app (using Maven build tool)

But this document has only instructions for Gradle build tool. For build tools other than grade, it is been asked there to use `pkl-codegen-java` dependency which when I use it gets in to conflict with `pkl-spring` dependency due to lot of duplicate classes

This is my maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.pkl-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>pkl-spring</artifactId>
  <version>0.15.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

When i also add `pkl-codegen-java`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.pkl-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>pkl-codegen-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.25.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Then i get this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.basepom.maven:duplicate-finder-maven-plugin:1.4.0:check (default) on project adventureservService: Found duplicate classes/resources! -> [Help 1]
```

```
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.expression.unary.UnaryMinusNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.expression.unary.UnaryMinusNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.frame.ReadAuxiliarySlotNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.frame.ReadEnclosingAuxiliarySlotNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.frame.ReadEnclosingFrameSlotNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.frame.ReadEnclosingFrameSlotNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.frame.ReadFrameSlotNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.frame.ReadFrameSlotNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.frame.WriteAuxiliarySlotNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.frame.WriteFrameSlotNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.frame.WriteFrameSlotNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.internal.BlackholeNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.internal.BlackholeNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.internal.GetBaseModuleClassNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.internal.GetClassNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.internal.GetClassNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.internal.IsInstanceOfNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.internal.IsInstanceOfNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.internal.ToStringNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.internal.ToStringNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction0Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction0NodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction1Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction1NodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction2Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction2NodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction3Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction3NodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction4Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction4NodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction5Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.lambda.ApplyVmFunction5NodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.ClassMember
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.ClassMethod
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.ClassNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.ClassProperty
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.DefaultPropertyBodyNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.DelegateToExtraStorageMapOrParentNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.DelegateToExtraStorageObjNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.DelegateToExtraStorageObjOrParentNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.FunctionNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.Lambda
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.LocalTypedPropertyNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.Member
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.ModuleNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.ObjectMember
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.ObjectMethodNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.PropertyTypeNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.TypeAliasNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.TypeCheckedPropertyNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.TypeCheckedPropertyNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.TypedPropertyNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.UnresolvedClassMemberNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.UnresolvedFunctionNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.UnresolvedMethodNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.UnresolvedPropertyNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.member.UntypedObjectMemberNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.repl.ResolveClassMemberNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.GetParentForTypeNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.IdentityMixinNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.ResolveDeclaredTypeNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.ResolveQualifiedDeclaredTypeNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.ResolveSimpleDeclaredTypeNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.TypeCastNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.TypeConstraintNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.TypeConstraintNodeGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.TypeNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.TypeNodeFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.TypeTestNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.UnresolvedTypeNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.ast.type.VmTypeMismatchException
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.FileResolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.ModuleKey
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.ModuleKeyFactories
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.ModuleKeyFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.ModuleKeys
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.ModulePathResolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.PathElement
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.ProjectDependenciesManager
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.ResolvedModuleKey
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.module.ResolvedModuleKeys
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.packages.Checksums
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.packages.Dependency
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.packages.DependencyMetadata
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.packages.PackageAssetUri
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.packages.PackageLoadError
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.packages.PackageResolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.packages.PackageResolvers
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.packages.PackageUri
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.packages.PackageUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.parser.ErrorStrategy
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.parser.LexParseException
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.parser.Lexer
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.parser.Parser
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.parser.antlr.PklLexer
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.parser.antlr.PklParser
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.parser.antlr.PklParserBaseVisitor
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.parser.antlr.PklParserVisitor
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.project.CanonicalPackageUri
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.project.DeclaredDependencies
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.project.Package
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.project.Project
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.project.ProjectDependenciesResolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.project.ProjectDeps
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.project.ProjectPackager
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.repl.ReplRequest
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.repl.ReplResponse
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.repl.ReplServer
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.resource.Resource
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.resource.ResourceReader
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.resource.ResourceReaders
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.BaseModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.BenchmarkModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.CertificateUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.FileSystemManager
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.Identifier
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.Iterators
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.JsonnetModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.KeyLookupSuggestions
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.LoggerImpl
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.MathModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.MemberLookupSuggestions
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.MinPklVersionChecker
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.MirrorFactories
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.ModuleCache
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.ModuleInfo
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.ModuleResolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.NullReceiverException
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.PlatformModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.ProjectModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.ReaderBase
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.ReflectModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.ReleaseModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.ResourceManager
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.SemVerModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.SettingsModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.StackTraceGenerator
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.StackTraceRenderer
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.StdLibModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.TestModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.TestResults
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.TestRunner
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmBugException
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmClass
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmCollection
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmContext
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmDataSize
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmDuration
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmDynamic
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmEvalException
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmException
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmExceptionBuilder
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmExceptionRenderer
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmFileDetector
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmFunction
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmIntSeq
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmLanguage
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmLanguageProvider
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmList
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmListing
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmMap
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmMapping
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmNull
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmObject
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmObjectLike
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmPair
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmRegex
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmSafeMath
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmSet
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmStackOverflowException
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmTypeAlias
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmTyped
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmTypes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmTypesGen
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmUndefinedValueException
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmValue
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmValueConverter
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmValueRenderer
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.VmValueVisitor
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.runtime.XmlModule
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.service.ExecutorSpiImpl
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.settings.PklSettings
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.AbstractRenderer
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.ExternalMemberNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.ExternalMethod0Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.ExternalMethod1Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.ExternalMethod2Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.ExternalMethod3Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.ExternalMethod4Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.ExternalMethod5Node
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.ExternalMethodNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.ExternalPropertyNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.LanguageAwareNode
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.PathConverterSupport
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.PathSpecParser
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.PklConverter
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.PklName
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.VmObjectFactories
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.VmObjectFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.AnyNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.AnyNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.BaseNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.BaseNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.BooleanNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.BooleanNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ClassNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ClassNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.CollectionNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.DataSizeNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.DataSizeNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.DurationNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.DurationNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.DynamicNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.DynamicNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.FloatNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.FloatNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function0Nodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function0NodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function1Nodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function1NodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function2Nodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function2NodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function3Nodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function3NodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function4Nodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function4NodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function5Nodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.Function5NodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.FunctionNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.FunctionNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.IntNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.IntNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.IntSeqNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.IntSeqNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.JsonRendererNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.JsonRendererNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ListNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ListNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ListingNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ListingNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.MapNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.MapNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.MappingNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.MappingNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.MergeSort
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ModuleClassNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ModuleClassNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.PListRendererNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.PListRendererNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.PairNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.PairNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.PcfRenderer
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.PcfRendererNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.PcfRendererNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.PropertiesRendererNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.PropertiesRendererNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.RegexMatchFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.RegexNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.RegexNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ResourceNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.ResourceNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.SetNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.SetNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.StringNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.StringNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.TypedNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.TypedNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.YamlRendererNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.base.YamlRendererNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.benchmark.BenchmarkUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.benchmark.MicrobenchmarkNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.benchmark.MicrobenchmarkNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.benchmark.OutputBenchmarkNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.benchmark.OutputBenchmarkNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.benchmark.ParserBenchmarkNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.benchmark.ParserBenchmarkNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.json.ParserNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.json.ParserNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.jsonnet.RendererNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.jsonnet.RendererNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.math.MathNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.math.MathNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.platform.PlatformNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.platform.PlatformNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.protobuf.RendererNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.protobuf.RendererNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.reflect.ClassNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.reflect.ClassNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.reflect.DeclaredTypeNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.reflect.DeclaredTypeNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.reflect.ReflectNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.reflect.ReflectNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.reflect.TypeNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.reflect.TypeNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.BaseMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.BenchmarkMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.EmptyMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.ExternalMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.JsonMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.JsonnetMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.MathMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.MemberRegistryFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.PlatformMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.ProtobufMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.ReflectMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.ReleaseMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.TestMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.XmlMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.registry.YamlMemberRegistry
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.release.ReleaseNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.release.ReleaseNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.test.TestNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.test.TestNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.test.report.JUnitReport
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.test.report.SimpleReport
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.test.report.TestReport
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.xml.RendererNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.xml.RendererNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.yaml.ParserNodes
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.stdlib.yaml.ParserNodesFactory
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.AbstractCharEscaper
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.ArrayCharEscaper
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.ByteArrayUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.CodeGeneratorUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.CollectionUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.DurationUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.EconomicMaps
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.EconomicSets
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.ErrorMessages
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.GlobResolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.IoUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.LateInit
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.MathUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.MutableBoolean
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.MutableLong
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.MutableReference
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.Nonnull
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.NonnullByDefault
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.Nullable
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.Pair
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.StringBuilderWriter
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.StringSimilarity
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.StringUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.json.Json
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.json.JsonEscaper
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.json.JsonHandler
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.json.JsonParser
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.json.JsonWriter
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.json.Location
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.json.ParseException
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.properties.PropertiesUtils
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.xml.Xml10Validator
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.xml.Xml11Validator
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.xml.XmlValidator
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.Yaml11Emitter
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.Yaml12Emitter
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.YamlCompatEmitter
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.YamlEmitter
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.YamlEscaper
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.snake.Yaml11Resolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.snake.Yaml12Resolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.snake.YamlCompatEmitterResolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.snake.YamlCompatParserResolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.snake.YamlResolver
[WARNING]   org.pkl.core.util.yaml.snake.YamlUtils
[WARNING] Found duplicate classes/resources in runtime classpath.
```

The instructions in the pkl documentation isn't clear. Any help on this please ?